# Backup SQL objects using mssql-scripter

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, mssql-scripter

I'm making backup sql objects by mssql-scripter and it works like a charm if it comes to my local server (here I don't have to provide any user, just pointing server and db). The problem is I have to backup sql objects from client's database wchich has Azure Active Directory authentication method.
I'm providing server, database and my credentials (mail as user)

```
mssql-scripter -S server -d database -U user -P password -f destination --file-per-object
```

But I'm getting error:

```
Failed to connect to server 'server_name'. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open server "my_mail_domain" requested by the login.  The login failed.
```

Where im mistaking? I've read info to backup sql object using mssql-scripter, authentication has to be set as 'Windows Authentication'. Is this true or I can backup providing Azure credentials?

Answer (score 0):

This [has been documented](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-scripter/issues/246) as an issue already.

This is only supported with a custom `connection-string` parameter

```
mssql-scripter
  --connection-string "Server=server;Database=database;User Id=user;Password=password;Authentication=Active Directory Password" `
  -f destination `
  --file-per-object
```

---

Assuming you actually meant that you have a on-premises SQL Server, but the domain is Azure AD, then you just need to use `Integrated Security` ie normal Windows Authentication.

```
mssql-scripter
  --connection-string "Server=server;Database=database;Integrated Security=true" `
  -f destination `
  --file-per-object
```

Note that usernames and passwords are not used here, the currently logged in user is used.

Comment: Thank you, I've changed as you suggested, but now Im getting error:

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\username\\mssql-scripter': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

Do you have any idea where the problem lies?

Comment: Seems like you have the wrong path for the `mssql-scripter` app. Do you know where it's stored? That part I have not changed